# Check if location permission granted

Tags: windows-10, c#

I am currently building library and only when host app had location permission granted already then i will use location as part of my logic, otherwise i will have a different logic.

That being said, I only want to get the location when host app already got the permission. **Is there an API to check if the location permission in this app had been granted?**

```
var status = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
```

I am now using above API to prompt the window and this is not my desired way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location services and other app permissions work differently in Windows 10 compared to, say, Windows Phone 8.

With Windows 10, it's possible for a user to grant permission to access location services but later revoke that permission if they choose.

So before using location services, you **must** check each time if you have permission or not.

Comment: To check the location is fine, but is there a API to check if location service had been granted ?

Comment: That *is* the API to check for access, it returns a [status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocationaccessstatus.aspx)

Comment: I just ran the test again and realized that by calling `Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();` system prompt the window for use to grant the permission and return allowed/denied based on user's choice. However, what i want it check simply if there was a permission result already. I do not want to prompt any window.

Comment: That's what the call is designed to do. It will only prompt **once** unless permission is revoked. If you call `geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()` without checking for permission, and the user has no granted it, you'll get an Exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I got what I want. Much appreciated!